# How do I find the tangent line to this curve?

Tags: calculus

I have a two-part question I am having trouble understanding what the second part is asking me and how to do it.

**PART (a):** Use the definition of derivative to calculate $f'(1)$ for $f(x) = x^2 - 3x$

**PART (b):** Use the result in (a), find the equation of the tangent line to the curve of $f(x)= x^2 - 3x$ at the point $(1, −2)$.

How do I find the equation of the tangent line to the curve? could I get help with the steps so I know how to do the next similar problems?

Comment: The tangent line has slope $f'(1)$ and goes through $(1,-2)$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If I understood you correctly you could figure out Part a). The derivative of $f(x)=x^2-3x$ is $2x-3$. If evaluated at the point $x=1$, $f'(1)=-1$.

b) This is an example for a tangent line to a curve:

[image]

As you can see, the tangent line measures the slope of the curve at the point where they're intersecting. Do you remember how we can find the slope of a function?